# Python: create a subclass dynamically in class body

Tags: python, oop, metaprogramming, introspection

In the following snippet I'm trying to define a factory function which would return objects of different classes derived from `Hero` based on arguments.

```
class Hero:
    Stats = namedtuple('Stats', ['health', 'defence', 'attack',
                                 'mana', 'experience'])
    RaceMaxStats = OrderedDict([
        ('Knight', Stats(100, 170, 150, 0, inf)),
        ('Barbarian', Stats(120, 150, 180, 0, inf)),
        ('Sorceress', Stats(50, 42, 90, 200, inf)),
        ('Warlock', Stats(70, 50, 100, 180, inf))
    ])

    @staticmethod
    def def_race(race: str):
        return type(race, (Hero,), {'max': Hero.RaceMaxStats[race]})

    Races = OrderedDict([
        (race, Hero.def_race(race)) for race in RaceMaxStats.keys()
    ])

    def __init__(self, lord, health, defence, attack, mana, experience):
        self.race = self.__class__.__name__
        self.lord = lord
        self.stats = Hero.Stats(min(health, self.max.health),
                                min(defence, self.max.defence),
                                min(attack, self.max.attack),
                                min(mana, self.max.mana),
                                min(experience, self.max.experience))

    @staticmethod
    def summon(race, *args, **kwargs):
        return Hero.Races[race](*args, **kwargs)
```

With the intention of later using it like so:

```
knight = Hero.summon('Knight', 'Ronald', 90, 150, 150, 0, 20)
warlock = Hero.summon('Warlock', 'Archibald', 50, 50, 100, 150, 50)
```

The problem is that I cannot initialize the subclasses because `Hero` is not yet defined:

```
    (race, Hero.def_race(race)) for race in RaceMaxStats.keys()
NameError: name 'Hero' is not defined
```

Obviously, if I replaced the static method call with the direct `type()` call I would still need `Hero` to be defined. My question is how do I best implement this kind of factory. The priority is for the `summon()` method to retain the same signature, and to return instances of classes derived from `Hero`.

P.S. none of the code above has ever been run successfully, so it may contain other mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [classmethods](http://stackabuse.com/pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explained/) and define yours `Races` variable as a method which caches its result after its first call in a class variable. It would look like that:

```
@classmethod
def def_race(cls, race: str):
    return type(race, (cls,), {'max': cls.RaceMaxStats[race]})

_Races = None

@classmethod
def Races(cls, race):
    if cls._Races is None:
        cls._Races = OrderedDict([
           (race, cls.def_race(race)) for race in cls.RaceMaxStats.keys()
        ])
    return cls._Races[race]

@classmethod
def summon(cls, race, *args, **kwargs):
    return cls.Races(race)(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The `def_race` classmethod is okay, but `summon` requires `Races` to be defined, which is the class variable I'm having a problem with. It should contain subclasses of `Hero`, but those cannot be created at that point, since `Hero` is not yet defined.

Comment: You can define `races` as another `classmethod`, which sets the class variable if is not already done and return the correct race from the class variable once it is set.

Answer (score 0):

After the class definition, do `Hero.knight = Hero.summon(...)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
Hero('Knight', 'Ronald', 90, 150, 150, 0, 20).summon()
```

alternatively:

```
hero = Hero('Knight', 'Ronald', 90, 150, 150, 0, 20)
hero.summon()
```